# Can't prevent physics field from interacting with particle system using category bit mask

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I'd like to place multiple particle systems with corresponding fields into a single scene and toggle between them. The fields should only interact with specific particle systems. I'm unable to do so using the Xcode SceneKit document builder.

As per the Apple documentation:

> To determine whether a field affects a physics body, SceneKit performs a bitwise AND operation on the field’s category bit mask and the body’s categoryBitMask property. If the result is a nonzero value, SceneKit computes and applies the force of the field on the body. To determine whether a field affects the particles spawned by an SCNParticleSystem object, SceneKit performs the same check using the categoryBitMask property of the node containing the particle system.
>
> Use this property to create fields which affect only certain bodies in your scene. Reducing the number of bodies affected by fields can also improve simulation performance.

I've created a simple scene file that contains:

- A linear gravity field. It's category bit mask set to 2 in the Node inspector.
- A node. It's category bit mask set to 4 in the Node inspector.
- A spheric particle system, inside the above node. Affected by physics fields option checked. Category bit mask left at 1 in the Node inspector.

Doesn't matter what I set the category bit masks to. The physics field always interacts with the particle system. I've also tried setting the bit masks programmatically in a Playground to in a separate file with 3 particle systems with one field for each system with no luck. Using:

```
let effect1Mask = 0x1 << 1
let effect2Mask = 0x1 << 2
let effect3Mask = 0x1 << 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that the category bit mask cannot be set on the physics field within the scene graph builder, it isn't exposed. It must be set programatically. I was setting the mask on the physics field node, hence why it wouldn't work.